# Protecting Properties file?

Tags: java, security, properties

Do you guys know of any way that I could go about protecting my `properties` file so that only my program can alter it? I wouldn't want someone to be able to read the `properties` file either if it was possible.

Comment: if the you set the file's permission correctly (e.g. 711, assuming using `unix`), how will someone else get access to it?

Comment: You could encrypt it.

Comment: Usually a program will run with it's users permissions. So if the program has read/write access to a file, then the user running it will also have read/write access.

Comment: @BevynQ: Then you've got the problem of _where do you store the key?_ :-)

Comment: @Greg Kopff, hard code it in the program.

Comment: @BevynQ: Then you just have the same problem, just slightly harder. Anyone who can run the program can find the key and decrypt the file.  It would deter _some_ attackers, but not all (not the determined ones).

Comment: @Greg Kopff: Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at

```
Files.setPosixFilePermissions()
```

or

```
File.setReadOnly()
```

if it must be done in Java.

Answer (score 10):

You are asking a question in terms of absolutes, and there is no absolute way to do it. If your program can read and modify your file, then there must be a way for some other program or person to do it too.

File permissions may help, but can you trust the root or admin user?

Even if the permissions are right, can you trust other programs that run as your username?

Encrypting the file will make it more difficult for someone to read the file, but not to corrupt it. And a 'determined' person with access to your program will be able to find the decryption key (otherwise you could not read it yourself).

Bottom line is that you need to ask yourself "what reasonable steps can I take to make it not worth trying to access/read/change the file?"